# Using standard Libertine italic g and w in math mode with newtxmath

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath, math-fonts

I'd like to use the Libertine italic *w* and *g* as math italic letters, rather than the variant letters employed by `newtxmath` with the `libertine` option. The option `liby` allows one to revert to the Libertine *y*. What is the simplest way to accomplish the same for *w* and *g*?

Note 1: I know there might be good reasons to prefer a single-story *g* in mathematics. Here, I would like to use the double-story version.

Note 2: I'm aware of K. Hosny's Libertinus Math – and keeping an eye on its development. At the moment, I'd prefer to stick with pdfLaTeX/Type 1 fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about “g” and “v”, because the “w” is exactly the same as the italic one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{altitalic}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{altitalic}{bold}{\tx@enc}{\rmdefaultB}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathord}{altitalic}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathord}{altitalic}{`v}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathit}{altitalic}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$abgwv$ \textit{gwv} $\mathit{abgwv}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output without the changes:

[image]

Without a new symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\mathchardef\mathg=\numexpr"7000+`g\relax
\mathchardef\mathv=\numexpr"7000+`v\relax
\begingroup\lccode`~=`g \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathit{\mathg}}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`v \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathit{\mathv}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathcode`g="8000
  \mathcode`v="8000
}

\begin{document}
$abgwv$ \textit{gwv} $\mathit{abgwv}$
\end{document}
```